# Lightning Maps Not Working in Communities - [Solved]!

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, map, lightning-community, csp

The following problem persists when loading a lightning:map in a community page:

```
Refused to frame 'https://maps.a.forceusercontent.com/' because it violates the 
following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'
```

Your users will see something like this:
[image: failed request]

"Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension."

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please include the *solution* in the Answer section, and then [edit] your question such that it only includes the actual *question*. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty obviously this is not okay, and in order to allow the maps go to
Setup > CSP Trusted Sites > New

Enter the following in the url:
`https://*.forceusercontent.com`
Name it however you like, with an end result of something like this:
[image]

```
Trusted_Site_Name   community_lightning_maps
Trusted_Site_URL    https://*.forceusercontent.com
Active  Checked
Context All
```

You may have to republish your community.

End result by adding the record is this (lightning map with pin, and popup window):
[image]